# Terminal - Unzip all .gz files in a folder without combining resulting files

Tags: terminal, zip, gzip, extract, gunzip

I have a folder, TestFolder, that contains several .gz files. Each .gz file is a folder containing several sub-directories, with the deepest level of each .gz file containing 5 text files. For example, extracting one of the .gz files ultimately has 5 files at the deepest level of the directory, like:

Users/me/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/TextFile1.txt

Users/me/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/TextFile2.txt

Users/me/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/TextFile3.txt

Users/me/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/TextFile4.txt

Users/me/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolder4/subfolder5/subfolder6/TextFile5.txt

when I run gunzip -r /Users/myuser/Desktop/TestFolderParent/TestFolder  in terminal, it extracts all of the .gz files, each as a single text file containing all 5 constituent text files concatenated together. Is there any way to instead run a command to extract each .gz file and return each of the 5 constituent text files as a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

`.gz` files themselves do not and cannot contain "several sub-directories". The gzip format compresses a *single file*, and that's it. `gunzip` will extract exactly one file from one `.gz` file.

That single file can itself be an uncompressed archive of files. That is often done using the tar archiver, so you end up with a `.tar.gz` file. Is that what you have? Then you need to use `tar`, not `gunzip` to extract the files.

Comment: thanks for the insight - perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology, but I have a .zip file, and when I open that, I have a folder with 20+ .gz files. then, when I open a single one of the .gz files, I see folder A, which contains subfolder B, which contains subfolder C, etc, until I get to the lowest level, containing 5 .txt files. is there anyway to go from either the original .zip or each .gz file and output the 5 .txt files, each as a separate file?

Comment: _"when I open a single one of the .gz files, I see folder A, which contains subfolder B, which contains subfolder C, etc"_ makes no sense to me. Exactly how do you "open" a .gz file, and how are you "seeing" folders in the result of that?